# git error: "The remote end hung up unexpectedly, invalid characters in (..path..)"

Tags: git, tortoisegit, git-bash

I am getting this error on my windows machine, both from tortoiseGIT/ GIT UI/ command line

```
fatal: invalid characters in /apps/saturn
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly

git did not exit cleanly (exit code 128)
```

Could someone suggest what's wrong with it, and what invalid characters the error message is referring to

Comment: Do @dhirendra-singh you have tried to clone remote repo, and then got the error?

Answer (score 0):

I have never used git under Windows systems, but Linux perror says

```
> perror 128
OS error code 128:  Key has been revoked
```

So maybe you have some issues with loggin to foreign host to which you have remote configured.